# how to calculate estimated time accuracy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I'm developing a todo app ,  when the user creates a new project they input title and a ruff estimated time to measure how good they plan projects .on project finish user is redirected to projects stats route in which I'm calculating the accuracy of thier estimation :

```
    const diff_minutes=(dt2, dt1)=> 
    {
        var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
        diff /= 60;
        return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
    }


    const started_at=project.started_at
    const finished_at=project.finished_at
    const estmated_time =project.estmated_time // minutes

    const project_duration_in_minutes =diff_minutes( started_at,finished_at);
    const accuracy =  -(project_duration_in_minutes  - estmated_time )/100
```

so the idea is the lower `project_duration_in_minutes`  is from the estmatedtime the better the accuracy is and vice versa  . for example :

```
  const estmated_time = 10  
  const project_duration_in_minutes  = 15 
  const accuracy =  -(project_duration_in_minutes  - est  )/100 //accuracy = -50%
```

```
  const estmated_time = 10  
  const project_duration_in_minutes  = 5
  const accuracy =  -(project_duration_in_minutes  - est  )/100 //accuracy = 50%
```

this kind of does it but I would love to see a better approach .

Comment: Assuming your main problem is the negative distance between estimated time and project duration. Use `Math.abs` to avoid negative numbers:  
`accuracy =  Math.abs(project_duration_in_minutes  - est)/100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`actual_time / estimated_time` gives you the difference in time as a ratio. So estimated 10 minutes, took 5 minutes = 0.5x the estimated time. Multiply by 100 for a percent.

You seem to be looking for high numbers when the time was less than expected. `estimated_time / actual_time` gives you the difference in speed as a ratio. So estimated 10 minutes, took 5 minutes = 2x the estimated speed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few alternatives here:

1. Add an `abs` method to your function, since accuracy doesn't need a positive/negative indicator in your case.
2. In your current formula, if actual time exceeds the estimate by a big margin, you'll get undesirable results. Instead of using a linear function, you could also use an exponential one:

```
Accuracy = 100* e^-(abs(est-project_duration_in_minutes)/project_duration_in_minutes)
```

Comment: thanks , I did not account for the undesirable results the exponential  method looks clean